What do you do to get the answer?
[Answer] what you see and you will get the answer.



The answer is

 EXTEND

Or if you prefer:

 $\color{yellow}{E}\color{blue}{X}\color{red}{T}\color{black}{E}\color{grey}{N}\color{green}{D}$
 where the color is in order based on line crossings (over/under)

Why

 If you extend the black lines you get a normal E, blue lines you get X, red lines you get T, yellow lines, an E backwards the grey an N and the green a D…
 


 All these letters spell out EXTEND…


Yup well done !
